# Multiplying an HTML form input with a select option value

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I want users to select a specific price option and quantity from menus and have the total calculated automatically. i.e. (its price) * (the quantity or no. of products).

this is the code.

Please Select Your Academic Level

```
<select name="ac_level" id="ac_level" required="">
<option id="1" value="highschool">Highschool</option>
<option id="2"value="college">College</option>
<option id="3" value="university">University</option>
<option id="4" value="masters">Masters</option>
<option id="5" value="phd">PhD</option>
</select>
```

Number of Pages

```
<input name="pages" id="number" required="" type="number" min=1 />
<input name="total" id="total" type="text" readonly />
<!-- #total = #number * #ac_level -->
```

Comment: There is really no effort demonstrated here. Where are the prices, where are the quantity inputs, where is the first attempt to a script?

Comment: It sounds like you need to try some simple javascript introduction. It would be possible to solve this in a few different ways, (either client-side or server-side). I would try googling, "manipulating html forms with javascript" (there are already many answers on this topic on this site.)

Comment: @trincot I am really sorry about that. I tried writing a script but it didn't work so I thought it would be better to submit one without the script (just to avoid confusion).

Comment: @AlexxRoche I will definitely look it up... since I am a complete noob here I am not much aware of the specific terms. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js">   </script>
        <script>

            $(document).ready(function(){

                $(document).on("change","#selectboxnumbers",function(){
                    //user is user picks new option
                    var value1 =0,value2 = 0;

                    value1 = $("#selectboxnumbers option:selected").attr("value") * 1;
                    value2 = $("#value2").val() * 1;

                    if(value1 != "" && value2 != "" && value1 != "undefined" && value2 != "undefined"){
                        $("#score").html("$" + Math.round(value1 * value2));
                    }
                });
                $("input").on("keyup change",function(){
                    //user is typing so will trigger this
                    var value1 =0,value2 = 0;

                    value1 = $("#selectboxnumbers option:selected").attr("value");
                    value2 = $("#value2").val();

                    if(value1 != "" && value2 != "" && value1 != "undefined" && value2 != "undefined"){
                        $("#score").html("$" + Math.round(value1 * value2));
                    }
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>

        Enter Value 1: 
        <select name="ac_level" id="selectboxnumbers">
            <option id="1" value="32">Item 1 - $32</option>
            <option id="2" value="55.93">Item 2 - $55.93</option>
            <option id="3" value="88.27">Item 3 - $88.27</option>
            <option id="4" value="2">Item 4 - $2</option>
            <option id="5" value="1">Item 5 - $1</option>
        </select><br>

        Enter Value 2: <input type="number" id="value2">

        <p id="score"></p>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Good answer, (works for me), but why " value1 = value1 = " ?

Comment: @linc I tried this code directly on my site but it didn't work. I also tried it on dreamweaver but it says that the following line has an error. I don't know why.
'{
            $("#score").html("$" + Math.round(value1 * value2));
        }'

Comment: @FaizanAhmed i'm not sure why it doesn't work -- I've tried this on my side directly -- let me check again and see that everything works

Comment: ahhh -- its my example -- its missing a bracket .. will revise it quickly